# HttpListener to handle requests async (c# 4)

Tags: c#-4.0, httplistener

I have a server listening for requests using HttpListener.Listen() with support for cancellation using CancellationTokenSource.Token. This is on c# 4.0.
The calling code:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
    myServer = new MyServer();
    myServer.Listen(new[] { "http://*:8085/" }, cancel.Token);
});
```

MyServer:

```
public void Listen(IEnumerable<string> prefixes, CancellationToken cancel)
{
  httpListener = new HttpListener();
  foreach(var p in prefixes) httpListener.Prefixes.Add(p);

  httpListener.Start();

  // watch for cancellation
  while(!cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    var result = httpListener.BeginGetContext(callback =>
      {
        var listener = (HttpListener)callback.AsyncState;
        if(!listener.IsListening) return;

        var httpContext = listener.EndGetContext(callback);
        // handle the request in httpContext, some requests can take some time to complete
      }, httpListener);

    while(result.IsCompleted == false)
    {
      if(cancel.IsCancellationRequested) break;
      Thread.Sleep(100); // sleep and recheck
    }
  }
  httpListener.Stop();
}
```

So far it seems to work fine, but it seems like an overly long piece of code.
I tried to use FromAsync() as such:

```
public void Listen(IEnumerable<string> prefixes, CancellationToken cancel)
{
  httpListener = new HttpListener();
  foreach(var p in prefixes) httpListener.Prefixes.Add(p);

  httpListener.Start();

  while(!cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    Task.Factory.FromAsync<HttpListenerContext>(httpListener.BeginGetContext, httpListener.EndGetContext, null).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
      var httpContext = t.Result;
      // do stuff
    }, cancel);
  }
  httpListener.Stop();
}
```

but what happens is i will run out of memory very quickly because many Tasks are created inside the while loop.
Any suggestions on how to resolve this problem? or how to clean up my first attempt?
I saw some answers on some other threads but those use .net 5.0 while my project is on .net 4.0.